# Scatter plot with bar markers

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to essentially make a scatter plot where instead of points, the markers are bars that connect the point to the bottom of the graph (like a histogram). My problem is that my graph has something like 30 points and the x-axis labels are smashed together.  I tried doing it with Histograms to no avail, and tried doing it with BarChart with a bit more success, but there are so many markers on the x-axis that you can't read them.  My problems would be solved if I could specify only a few markers at certain positions.  Can anyone help?

Below is what the graph looks like: I think it's pretty self-explanatory what the problem is even just by looking at it.[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `Filling` option of `ListPlot[]`?

Comment: What @J.M. suggested plus make your own x axis tick labels or tick function

Comment: Try plotting your data with `ListStepPlot`, use the `"Center"` arguement.

Answer (score 6):

It's a good question and something I've dealt with recently when essentially trying to plot a histogram but when I already have the data binned. After using `ListLinePlot` with `InterpolationOrder->0` I discovered the very useful `ListStepPlot` function. Allow me to demonstrate.

If we have some samples we can just use `Histogram`:

```
    samples = RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[4, 1, 2], 100000];
    Histogram[samples, {0, 10, 0.1}, "Probability"]
```

[image]

However, if you already have the data points corresponding to the elements of the histogram, as in your case.

```
    {binEdges, counts} = HistogramList[samples, {0, 10, 0.1}, "Probability"];
    dataPoints = Transpose[{MovingAverage[binEdges, 2], counts}];
```

[image]

Then as you say, `BarChart` is not so good:

```
    BarChart[dataPoints[[;; , 2]], ChartLabels -> dataPoints[[;; , 1]]]
```

[image]

However, `ListStepPlot` makes things very easy!

```
    ListStepPlot[dataPoints, "Center", Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

And you can use all the normal plot styling functionality

```
    ListStepPlot[dataPoints, "Center", 
      PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.982864`, 0.7431472`, 0.3262672`], 
      Filling -> Axis, 
      FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], 
      Frame -> True, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None, 
      GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Good Luck!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way would be like the following. Assume that this is your list:

```
lst = Table[{i, i^(1/2)*Exp[-i]}, {i, 0, 4, 0.05}];
```

And here is you histogram-like plot:

```
 Show[Graphics[{Blue, 
     Rectangle[{#[[1]] - 0.025, 0}, {#[[1]] + 0.025, #[[2]]}]}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True] & /@ lst]
```

looking as follows:

[image]

Have fun!